# Automate zeppelin notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook, databricks

Hi I just watched a databricks webinar where they are automating a databricks notebook and they have a dependent jar that the notebook is dependant on as well.   Can you do this Zeppelin?   Like calling the script in a notebook from a bash script.  To execute the notebook like a script. I would like to use my notebooks in the production environment in this manner.

Comment: What do you mean by automating?

Comment: I also agree with @cricket_007 . I'm not sure what "automating" without any context. Please review your question as I'm voting to close for it being unclear.

Comment: Ok making a change

Comment: I still don't understand.

Comment: Databricks has a notebook for writing Spark jobs. It then allows you to set up a schedule to run the notebook automatically, like crontab. I think @Mike wants to know if Zeppelin had a similar functionality. A way to automate a Zeppelin workbook would be to invoke the workbook from command line. That has been answered [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256619/how-to-run-zeppelin-notebook-from-command-line-automatically)

Comment: If the question is around scheduling notebooks to run, that functionality has been added to the API and UI.  https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.1/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#cron-jobs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a cron job and use the Rest API.  This is a  link for creating a cron job. https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.0/rest-api/rest-notebook.html#add-cron-job