# Create a notebook with Zeppelin Rest api and bind to specific interpreter setting

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is there way to bind a notebook to a specific interpreter setting while create the notebook through Zeppelin rest api?

UI give a dropdown of all the setting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run zeppelin notebook from command line (automatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36256619/how-to-run-zeppelin-notebook-from-command-line-automatically)